# FiddlerScript throws NullReferenceException on headers.ExistsAndContains

Tags: fiddler

This is driving me nuts and it *may* be something simple, but every time I call the following from Fiddler script is throws a NullReferenceException:

```
if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "html")){...
```

This is straight off the [Fiddler script knowledge base](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse) and I've got the same thing happening on two different Win 8 machines. It seems that oSession.oResponse.headers is null and yes, I am calling this from within OnBeforeRequest!

Same deal with oSession.responseBodyBytes - it looks like the response is null inside OnBeforeRequest. Otherwise Fiddler is behaving normally, traffic proxies through just fine and everything else looks good.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oResponse.headers` and `oSession.responseBodyBytes` objects don't exist until after the request has been sent to the server and the response has been read back. If you want to interact with the Response headers and body, do so inside the `OnBeforeResponse` function instead.

*The KB was mangled a bit when updated for the new site. I'll file a bug to have this made more explicit.*

Comment: Ok, so it *was* something simple! Thanks Eric, think I was just running on autopilot and editing after existing code that genuinely was meant to change the request, probably didn't help referring to the KB and seeing code to deal with the response in under OnBeforeRequest.